# how to deal with multiple value for multiple field in single table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have one table user in which there are 3 fields which have multiple values. fields are process,project and manager. User can select multiple values for these fields.

As of now I created separate table for each field, like user_process,user_project and user_manager. all these table have reference key to master user table. Is it right approach ? I Have to create 4 tables to store a set of single record. Is there any better way to do this which gives better performance.

Comment: This is the best approach in my opinion, it might require multiple tables, but only other option is to save it in multiple columns in the main table, but that's just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can go with that design too.More flexible design could be:
User(id,u1,u2)
Process(id,p1,p2)
Project(id,pr1,pr2)
Manager(id,m1,m2,m3)
UserProcess(fk_to_user,fk_to_process) :[ M:M relationship]
UserProject(fk_to_user,fk_to_project) :[ M:M relationship]
UserManager(fk_to_user,fk_to_manager) :[ M:M relationship]

Here I am assuming that:
1. there can be user who come under many process or many users that come under single process.
2. there can be user who has assigned to many projects or many users assigned to single project.
2. there can be user who reports to many managers or many users that reports to single manager.
If anything above does not fit to you requirement you can ignore corresponding  M:M relationship

Comment: But creating 3 tables to store one set of record decrease the performance when table size will huge, When I need I data of one user I have to write query which joins the 4 table, and i know joins create  major issues some times. As of now I given index on each every reference key which may be helpful.